# Remove 'watermark' from pdf using libredraw output size very large

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, pdftk

I have a pdf with a watermark at the bottom of the page.  I open the pdf with libredraw and the watermark appears as a text box, I highlight it and delete. I then click the export as pdf and I save the file.  The new filesize is similar to the original, say 2.6mb.

Now, I then use pdftk to burst the edited file into individual pages.  Each page is about 2.6mb.  However, if I just use pdftk on the original file before removing the watermark, the individual pages are all 100-300kb.

Why is there such a difference in output sizes between the edited pdf and origianl pdf?

d

Comment: Most likely, the original PDF contains the text as text, while the output has converted everythng into images (which are larger than the corresponding text)

Comment: It's difficult to analyze what might be going on here.  There could be a huge amount of preamble -- e.g. page definitions, font outlines etc, and a small amount of actual text.

Comment: The original is a scan using a iphone scanning app. I attempted to remove the watermark programically, but never worked.  So, I have to open each page, remove the text box, then export as pdf.  Just time consuming, was looking for a method to speed it up.